# Can't get an information inside an response object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, search, suitescript2.0

I'm loading a saved search and trying to get some specific information from the results.

I've tried many ways to get and handle the results, some of them worked, but not automatically.

Worked manually:

```
var resultado = [{"recordType":"vendorbill","id":"13315","values": 
    {"entity":[{"value":"5253","text":"PREVENCAO TOTAL SEGURANCA DO TRABALHO E 
    CURSOS LTDA ME"}],"custbody1":"123456"}}, 
    {"recordType":"vendorbill","id":"13316","values":{"entity": 
    [{"value":"5253","text":"PREVENCAO TOTAL SEGURANCA DO TRABALHO E CURSOS 
    LTDA ME"}],"custbody1":"123456"}}, 
    {"recordType":"vendorbill","id":"13424","values":{"entity": 
    [{"value":"6280","text":"A. A. POSTO DE SERVICOS 
    LTDA"}],"custbody1":"12345678"}}];
    log.debug(resultado);
for (var a in resultado){
    var dados = resultado[a];
    var dados1 = dados['values'];
    var dados2 = dados1['entity'];
    var nota = dados1['custbody1'];
    log.debug("Numero da nota: " + nota);
    var dados3 = dados2[0];
    var vendorId = dados3['value'];
    log.debug("Id do Fornecedor: " + vendorId);
}
```

I need working with the automatic result, like this:

```
var resultado = busca.run().getRange({
    start: 0,
    end: 999
});
```

I expect to get those specific informations: the "value" of the entity, and the "custbody1". When I do with the automatic search, it returns undefined, or and error saying 'can't get inforamation from undefined'.
This just worked on the Netsuite Debugger...

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What **exactly** does `getRange()` return? Have you tried debugging the `resultado` value?

Comment: @Phil When i debug the result of the getRange() function returns exactly the same value of the 'resultado' variable in the first example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is how you're trying to get the values from the result. When you pass your own test data, you're using an object that's structured *exactly* the way you wrote it. But when you get a result from a search (created or loaded), the object that's returned isn't actually structured the way you see it when you log it to the console. This is why your test is working but the search method isn't.

As documented in the Help Center, you have to use **`Result.getValue(fieldId)`** or **`Result.getText(fieldId)`** to get a value/text from a result field. You can't access a value directly the way you would with any other object (dot or bracket notation).

To get the values you need, do this instead:

```
var resultado = busca.run().getRange(0, 1000);

for (var a in resultado) {
  var dados = resultado[a];

  var entityValue = dados.getValue('entity'); // 5253
  var entityText = dados.getText('entity'); // PREVENCAO TOTAL SEGURANCA DO TRABALHO E CURSOS LTDA ME
  var custbody1Value = dados.getValue('custbody1'); // 123456
}
```